# calling a pointer variable with pointer object error

Tags: c++

"for you to know Kova=Bucket this code written in Turkish words."

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;


class Kova

{

public:

void KovaCizdir(const char *dizi[6][6])
{
    dizi[0][0] = "";
    dizi[0][1] = "";
    dizi[0][2] = ".";
    dizi[0][3] = "|";
    dizi[0][4] = ".";
    dizi[0][5] = "";
    dizi[0][6] = "";
    dizi[1][0] = "";
    dizi[1][1] = ".";
    dizi[1][2] = "";
    dizi[1][3] = "";
    dizi[1][4] = "";
    dizi[1][5] = ".";
    dizi[1][6] = "";
    dizi[2][0] = ".";
    dizi[2][1] = "";
    dizi[2][2] = "";
    dizi[2][3] = "";
    dizi[2][4] = "";
    dizi[2][5] = "";
    dizi[2][6] = ".";
    dizi[3][0] = "#";
    dizi[3][1] = "";
    dizi[3][2] = "";
    dizi[3][3] = "";
    dizi[3][4] = "";
    dizi[3][5] = "";
    dizi[3][6] = "#";
    dizi[4][0] = "#";
    dizi[4][1] = "";
    dizi[4][2] = "";
    dizi[4][3] = "-";
    dizi[4][4] = "";
    dizi[4][5] = "";
    dizi[4][6] = "#";
    dizi[5][0] = "#";
    dizi[5][1] = "";
    dizi[5][2] = "";
    dizi[5][3] = "";
    dizi[5][4] = "";
    dizi[5][5] = "";
    dizi[5][6] = "#";
    dizi[6][0] = "#";
    dizi[6][2] = "#";
    dizi[6][3] = "#";
    dizi[6][4] = "#";
    dizi[6][5] = "#";
    dizi[6][6] = "#";

};

void KovaOlustur(int kovaSayisi)
{
    for (int t = 0; t < kovaSayisi; t++)
    {
        char *Kovalar[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            Kovalar[i] = new char[6];
        }
    }
};

};


int main()
{

int kovaSayisi;

cout << "Kova Sayisi : ";
cin >> kovaSayisi;

Kova *kova = new Kova();

kova->KovaOlustur(kovaSayisi);

kova->KovaCizdir(*Kovalar[6][6]);

}
```

identifier "Kovalar" is undefined error
How can I solve this problem, I'm new at using pointers.
I'm trying to make a bucket shape with pointers and later the user can change the field of the buckets and change their numbers.
It can include many logic errors I want to know all of it.

Comment: `char *Kovalar[6]` is a local variable in the `for` loop in `Kova::KovaOlustur()`. It's just not existing outside of that `for` loop.

Comment: but i have to use for loop for my purpose. How can i solve this ?

Comment: @MrAlbino `kova->KovaCizdir(*Kovalar[6][6]);` -- Describe what you're trying to do here.  It looks like you're guessing how to write C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code- Kovalar is local variable of the `KovaOlustur` method, so that is not visible to the out side worls. And along with that there are some minor flaws in the code you provided, let me help you correcting them:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;


class Kova

{

private: 
    char *Kovalar[6]; // make the Kovalar a member variable of the class

public:
 Kova(int kovaSayisi) {
     KovaOlustur( kovaSayisi);
     // otherwise you can move the whole code of KovaOlustur code here like:
     /* for (int t = 0; t < kovaSayisi; t++)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            Kovalar[i] = new char[6];
        }
    }*/
 }

void KovaCizdir() // no parameters required, as the data is now a member variable
{
    // anything in double quote "" is treated as a const char* in c/c++
    // but you are trying to access the Kovalar with 2 indices which make that to be 
    // char - so change the double quotes "" to single quotes ''
    Kovalar[0][0] = ' '; 
    Kovalar[0][1] = ' '; 
    Kovalar[0][2] = '.';
    Kovalar[0][3] = '|';
    Kovalar[0][4] = '.';
    Kovalar[0][5] = ' ';
    Kovalar[0][6] = ' ';
    Kovalar[1][0] = ' ';
    Kovalar[1][1] = '.';
    Kovalar[1][2] = ' ';
    Kovalar[1][3] = ' ';
    Kovalar[1][4] = ' ';
    Kovalar[1][5] = '.';
    Kovalar[1][6] = ' ';
    Kovalar[2][0] = '.';
    Kovalar[2][1] = ' ';
    Kovalar[2][2] = ' ';
    Kovalar[2][3] = ' ';
    Kovalar[2][4] = ' ';
    Kovalar[2][5] = ' ';
    Kovalar[2][6] = '.';
    Kovalar[3][0] = '#';
    Kovalar[3][1] = ' ';
    Kovalar[3][2] = ' ';
    Kovalar[3][3] = ' ';
    Kovalar[3][4] = ' ';
    Kovalar[3][5] = ' ';
    Kovalar[3][6] = '#';
    Kovalar[4][0] = '#';
    Kovalar[4][1] = ' ';
    Kovalar[4][2] = ' ';
    Kovalar[4][3] = '-';
    Kovalar[4][4] = ' ';
    Kovalar[4][5] = ' ';
    Kovalar[4][6] = '#';
    Kovalar[5][0] = '#';
    Kovalar[5][1] = ' ';
    Kovalar[5][2] = ' ';
    Kovalar[5][3] = ' ';
    Kovalar[5][4] = ' ';
    Kovalar[5][5] = ' ';
    Kovalar[5][6] = '#';
    Kovalar[6][0] = '#';
    Kovalar[6][2] = '#';
    Kovalar[6][3] = '#';
    Kovalar[6][4] = '#';
    Kovalar[6][5] = '#';
    Kovalar[6][6] = '#';
    // otherwise you can also write like this:
    /*Kovalar[0] = "  ./.  ";
    Kovalar[1] = " .   . ";
    Kovalar[2] = ".     .";
    Kovalar[3] = "#     #";
    Kovalar[4] = "#  -  #";
    Kovalar[5] = "#     #";
    Kovalar[6] = "#######"; */
}

void KovaOlustur(int kovaSayisi)
{
    for (int t = 0; t < kovaSayisi; t++)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            Kovalar[i] = new char[6];
        }
    }
}

};


int main()
{

int kovaSayisi;

cout << "Kova Sayisi : ";
cin >> kovaSayisi;

Kova *kova = new Kova(kovaSayisi); // here the variable kovaSayisi is not at all used, you can eliminate that

//kova->KovaOlustur(kovaSayisi); /* now no need of this call because this is done in the constructor itslef

kova->KovaCizdir(); // no need of passing the parameter, becuase the data is now a member of the class itself

}
```

I have provided inline comments for your understanding, hope this helps and solves your problem.

Thanks,

Rajkumar